# C# - Array of an different classes objectes

Tags: c#, arrays, class, testing

im sitting here with a bit problem.
I have to create a program to solve tests.
There's need to be one basic class, and 4 inheriting from it, all for other kind of tasks (some with 1 answer, some with numeric answer etc.).
Also need an task collection, an array of different class objects. Array containts different tasks, then i have to draw 10 tasks from it. Is there any easier way to do the task collection that im doing?

```
     public class Program
{

    public class Task
    {
        protected string contents;
        protected int nr_pyt;
    };

    public class Task4Answ : Task
    {
        private
            char odp;
        public
        Task4Answ(string contents1, int nr, string odp1)
        {
            contents = contents1;
            nr_pyt = nr;
            odp = odp1[0];
        }
    };

    public class TaskNumber : Task
    {
        private
            int odp;
        public
        TaskNumber(string contents1, int nr, int odp1)
        {
            contents = contents1;
            nr_pyt = nr;
            odp = odp1;
        }
    };

    public class TaskString : Task
    {
        private
            string odp;
        public
        TaskString(string contents1, int nr, string odp1)
        {
            contents = contents1;
            nr_pyt = nr;
            odp = odp1;
        }
    };

    public class TaskFewAnsw : Task
    {
        private
            string odp;
            string odpp;
            string odppp;
        public
        TaskFewAnsw(string contents1, int nr, string odp1,string odpp1, string odppp1)
        {
            contents = contents1;
            nr_pyt = nr;
            odp = odp1;
            odpp = odpp1;
            odppp = odppp1;
        }
    };

    public class TaskCollection
    {
        public Task[] collection;
        public TaskCollection()
        {
            collection = new Task[60];
            collection[0] = new Task4Answ("Ile jest por roku w Polsce? \na) 1 \nb) 2 \nc) 3 \nd) 4", 1, "d");
            collection[1] = new Task4Answ("Kto wygral tegoroczny Roland Garros? \na) Federer \nb) Djokovic \nc) Nadal \nd) Thiem", 1, "c");
            collection[2] = new Task4Answ("Kto jest premierem Polski? \na) Macierewicz \nb) Duda \nc) Kaczynski \nd) Szydlo", 1, "d");
            collection[3] = new Task4Answ("Ktore slowo kluczowe w C++ jest uzywane do deklarowania typu zmiennoprzecinkowego \na) Float \nb) Int \nc) Enum \nd) Struct", 1, "float");
            collection[4] = new Task4Answ("Ktory z podanych modyfikatorow dostepu pozwala na uzywanie zmiennych klasy bazowej w klasach pochodnych, a w innych klasach nie? \na) Domyslny \nb) Public \nc) Private \nd) Protected", 1, "d");
            collection[5] = new Task4Answ("Jakiego slowa kluczowego uzywamy do zwrocenia obiektu z funkcji? \na) Back \nb) Reversion \nc) Return \nd) Void", 1, "c");
            collection[6] = new Task4Answ("Ktory z samochodow nalezy do fabryki Volkswagenta? \na) Mondeo \nb) Passat \nc) Vectra \nd) Yaris", 1, "b");
            collection[7] = new Task4Answ("Ktory czlowiek na swiecie pierwszy stanal na ksiezycu? \na) Gagarin \nb) Lajka \nc) Armstrong \nd) Ahonen", 1, "c");
            collection[8] = new Task4Answ("Ktory z samochodow nalezy do fabryki Opla? \na) Mondeo \nb) Passat \nc) Vectra \nd) Yaris", 1, "c");
            collection[9] = new Task4Answ("Z iloma panstwami graniczy Polska? \na) 5 \nb) 6 \nc) 7 \nd) 8", 1, "c");
            collection[10] = new Task4Answ("Od ktorego roku Polska nalezy do Unii Europejskiej? \na) 2004 \nb) 2006 \nc) 2002 \nd) 2000", 1, "a");
            collection[11] = new Task4Answ("Kto jest obecnym prezesem PZPN? \na) Boniek \nb) Lato \nc) Listkiewicz \nd) Gmoch", 1, "a");
            collection[12] = new Task4Answ("Ktora z planet posiada charakterystyczny pierscien? \na) Neptun \nb) Jowisz \nc) Saturn \nd) Merkury", 1, "c");
            collection[13] = new Task4Answ("Za pomoca jakiego slowa kluczowego definiujemy szablony w C++? \na) Template \nb) Pattern \nc) Stencil \nd) Stereotype", 1, "a");
            collection[14] = new Task4Answ("Ktory z podanych jezykow posiada interfejsy? \na) C++ \nb) C \nc) C# \nd) HTML", 1, "c");
            collection[15] = new TaskNumber("Podaj date Bitwy Pod Grunwaldem", 15, 1410);
            collection[16] = new TaskNumber("Podaj maksymalna predkosc w terenie zabudowanym", 16, 50);
            collection[17] = new TaskNumber("W ktorym roku odbyly sie Mistrzostwa Europy w Pilce w Polsce?", 17, 2012);
            collection[18] = new TaskNumber("Ile bajtow pamieci zajmuje typ long w jezyku C++?", 18, 8);
            collection[19] = new TaskNumber("W ktorym roku w Polsce ogloszono stan wojenny?", 19, 1978);
            collection[20] = new TaskNumber("Po dodaniu dwoch zmiennych typu int, ile bajtow pamieci zajmie zmienna przechowujaca wynik tego dodawania?", 20, 4);
            collection[21] = new TaskNumber("Ile wynosi reszta z dzielenia liczby 60 przez liczbe 7?", 21, 4);
            collection[22] = new TaskNumber("Ile wynosi pierwiastek z liczby 49?", 22, 7);
            collection[23] = new TaskNumber("W ktorym roku rozpoczela sie II Wojna Swiatowa?", 23, 1939);
            collection[24] = new TaskNumber("W ktorym roku mial miejsce chrzest Polski?", 24, 966);
            collection[25] = new TaskNumber("Ile zlotych medali zdobyl Adam Malysz na Igrzyskach Olimpijskich?", 25, 0);
            collection[26] = new TaskNumber("Ile lat trwa kadencja prezydenta w Polscce", 26, 4);
            collection[27] = new TaskNumber("Jezeli na kazde 15 metrow kwadratowych przypada 6 wezy, ile wezy przypadnie na 90 metrow kwadratowych", 27, 36);
            collection[28] = new TaskNumber("W ktorym roku mial miejsce atak terrorystyczny na World Trade Center", 28, 2002);
            collection[29] = new TaskNumber("Jezeli 3 lata temu Ania ktora ma teraz 18lat byla 3 razy starsza od Tomka, to ile lat ma teraz Tomek", 29, 8);
            collection[30] = new TaskString("Podaj wzor chemiczny wody", 30, "H2O");
            collection[31] = new TaskString("Podaj gdzie urodzil sie Kopernik", 31, "Torun");
            collection[32] = new TaskString("Na jakim instrumencie gral Fryderyk Chopin", 32, "Fortepian");
            collection[33] = new TaskString("Podaj slowo kluczowe, ktorego uzywa sie do zwalniania pamieci w C++", 33, "Delete");
            collection[34] = new TaskString("Jak nazywa sie program w C# pelniacy role destruktora?", 34, "Garbage Collector");
            collection[35] = new TaskString("Jakiego slowa kluczowego uzywamy w C# do przyslaniania funkcji klasy bazowej?", 35, "Override");
            collection[36] = new TaskString("Jakie miasto jest stolica Kanady?", 36, "Ottawa");
            collection[37] = new TaskString("Jaka jest najwieksza wyspa na swiecie?", 37, "Grenlandia");
            collection[38] = new TaskString("Skad pochodzi sprinter Usain Bolt?", 38, "Jamajka");
            collection[39] = new TaskString("Jakiego slowa kluczowego uzywamy do deklarowania klas abstrakcyjnych w C#", 30, "Abstact");
            collection[40] = new TaskString("Jakiego slowa kluczowego uzywamy do deklarowania klas wirtualnych w C#", 40, "Virtual");
            collection[41] = new TaskString("Podaj slowo kluczowe, ktorego uzywa sie do deklarowania struktur w C# i C++", 41, "Struct");
            collection[42] = new TaskString("Jak nazywa sie dziedzina nauki, zajmujaca sie m.in kosmosem?", 42, "Astronomia");
        }

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TaskCollection T1= new TaskCollection();
            Task[] tab;
            tab = new Task[10];
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                tab[i] = T1.collection[i];
            }
            Console.WriteLine(tab[0]);
            System.Console.ReadKey();


        }
       };
```

Then here i have to draw 10 tasks from this collection, but i can't just copy it from collection cause all are from different classes.

Comment: What will you do once you have the Object? Can you tell the whole flow that the program should be doing?

Comment: Need to create an object which will be a drawed test from those 42 above, containing 10 tasks , then will get an answers from an user, and the last thing will be checking if answers are correct.

Comment: Unfortunately that's still not very clear. Could you post an example, with fewer Tasks but something that explains your requirements and expected results.

Comment: By the way `Task` is not a good name for a user-defined class, as that's already a `.NET` class name.

Comment: @Sach , here's the full program i wrote before : https://ideone.com/WNzw4G.

Comment: The thing is my profesor told me that is too less "objective", and there could be a lot of work in adding next task. That's why i want to keep answers now with contents.

Comment: @Dariokoko I _don't_ want the full program. That's simply too big and I can't go through that big a program without even knowing what it's supposed to do. What you should do is first _clearly_ explain in your original post what your requirement is, then where you're facing problems in your code.

Comment: Ok i edited my post, thats what i want to achieve, get an array with 10 tasks from my collection. The problem is i don't know how can i recognize, if it's TaskString, Task4Answ or other type.

Comment: Do you understand inheritance? Put methods in your `Task` class that will be overridden by the subclasses and have the methods perform the operation based on which class they are in.

Comment: @NetMage yeah i understand , but to be honest in this case i don't see any purpose to use methods in subclasses. Just need to create an object containing 10 different tasks.

Comment: You have accomplished your task, then. `tab` is an `array` containing 10 different tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first and direct question:

> The problem is i don't know how can i recognize, if it's TaskString, Task4Answ or other type.

This can be achieved by using `GetType()` method. Let's say you get the first element in your `collection`, and you want to identify what `type` it is.

```
var item = collection[i];
if (item.GetType().Name == "TaskString")
    // You have a TaskString object.
else if (item.GetType().Name == "Task4Answ")
    // You have a Task4Answ object
```

So that is easy.

However there's quite a few problems with your code. This sounds very homework-y, so instead of using your class structure, I'm using my own that resembles yours and illustrates the same problems. Hope you'll understand my explanations and be able to convert them and apply to your problem.

Say you have an `Employee` base class, and two sub-classes that inherit from it, namely, `EmpTypeOne` and `EmpTypeTwo`. Base class has the property `ID`, `EmpTypeOne` has `Name`, and `EmpTypeTwo` has `Name` and `City`.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class EmpTypeOne : Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public EmpTypeOne(int id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class EmpTypeTwo : Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public EmpTypeTwo(int id, string name, string city)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        City = city;
    }
}
```

What you're doing is creating a list of 'Employee' class objects, and put different sub-class instances into it. So later on, I assume, you want to get those different types of objects and use their member variables and the like. But that's your first problem.

When you create a list of your base-class objects, and put child-class objects in it, you will only be able to access the base-class properties/members in those *even though* they were created as child classes.

That is, you won't be able to do this:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
employees.Add(new EmpTypeOne(1, "Tim"));
employees[0].Name; // This won't be allowed because `employees[0]` is parent class and has no knowledge of the child-class property `Name`.
```

What you should do is, as NetMage advised in a comment, is put your methods in your base-class, then override them in your sub-classes to use their variables and get work done. For example, say you want to display the employee info, but based on different sub-classes you want to display different info in different formats. You could do something like this.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual void DisplayInfo()
    {

    }
}

public class EmpTypeOne : Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public EmpTypeOne(int id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public override void DisplayInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a Type A Employee");
        Console.WriteLine("ID : {0}, Name : {1}", ID, Name);
    }
}

public class EmpTypeTwo : Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public EmpTypeTwo(int id, string name, string city)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        City = city;
    }

    public override void DisplayInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a Type B Employee");
        Console.WriteLine("ID : {0}, Name : {1}, City : {2}", ID, Name, City);
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    List<Employee> emps = new List<Employee>();
    emps.Add(new EmpTypeOne(1, "Tim"));
    emps.Add(new EmpTypeTwo(2, "Jane", "Chicago"));

    emps[0].DisplayInfo();
    Console.WriteLine();
    emps[1].DisplayInfo();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Finally, your `TaskCollection` class implementation isn't very good either. The way you've done, you hard-code each child information. What you need to do is have a list of your base-class, and then add items to it later on. Something similar to:

```
public class EmployeeCollection
{
    public List<Employee> Employees;

    public EmployeeCollection()
    {
        Employees = new List<Employee>();
    }

    public void AddTypeOne(int id, string name)
    {
        if (Employees == null)
            Employees = new List<Employee>();
        Employees.Add(new EmpTypeOne(id, name));
    }

    public void AddTypeTwo(int id, string name, string city)
    {
        if (Employees == null)
            Employees = new List<Employee>();
        Employees.Add(new EmpTypeTwo(id, name, city));
    }
}
```

Then add objects to your list like so:

```
EmployeeCollection employees = new EmployeeCollection();
employees.AddTypeOne(1, "Tim");
employees.AddTypeTwo(2, "Jane", "Chicago");
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sach, didnt expect that anyone will explain me that good. If every teacher would be like you, everything would be easy.